# Does a pure spam manual penalty hurt the entire domain?

Tags: google-search-console, penalty

If a single url on a domain (that is not the home page, just a blog post) gets a pure spam manual penalty, does it hurt the ranking of the domain in general or does it just impact that individual url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is not always. Sometimes it will impact the entire domain other times it will not. Typically if a spammy url is part of the sites main menu it will end up impacting the entire website. If not, it will just be the urls that match the pattern provided